# У вас нет разрешения на запись в папку macos

Tags: консоль, macos

Хочу отредактировать файл hosts. Ввожу `sudo open /private/etc/hosts` открывается файл, затем при попытке редактирования *У Вас нет разрешения на запись в папку, в которой находится файл «hosts».*

Как это исправить?